# проблема с browser-sync

Tags: browsersync

не могу установить browser sync пишу все команды правильно путь верный но выскакивает ошибка cannot get если кто подскажет буду очень благодарен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тоже недавно была такая трабла, попробуй все файлы сложить в твоей папке proekt/ в папку, скажем, "app/", кроме всяких там package.json и при запуске пропиши 
$ browser-sync start --server 'app' --files 'app' (без $), находясь в консоли в папке "proekt/"  . Инфа взята отсюда https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line#start. Мне помогло.